# PYTHON Split String at space but keep the spaces

Tags: python, string, split, slice

I have a string

```
a = bla bla bla bla

v = re.split("\[(.*?)\]@", a)
```

I get:

```
v =['bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'bla']
```

I want:

```
v =['bla', ' ', 'bla', ' ', 'bla', ' ', 'bla']
```

I found this as possible solution but dont know how to apply it:

```
return a[::2]
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Always remember to google your question first, the link is first result to "python split strig keep separator"

Comment: Also your input + regex DOES NOT give the output you show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why you need it, but it can be done like so

```
import re
a = 'bla bla bla bla'
temp = re.sub(' ','\t \t',a)
result = temp.split('\t')
```

Comment: worked perfect. Thanks